# IMemberConfigurationExpression failing when upgrade AutoMapper from v3 to v6

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm trying to update our code from aotumapper v3 to v6 and having trouble with one helper method that is using IMemberConfigurationExpression.

```
    private void TreatEmptyStringsAsNull<TSource>(IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource> expression)
    {

        expression.Condition(ctx => ctx.SourceType != typeof(string) || (string)ctx.SourceValue != string.Empty); 
    }
```

And this method is called by: 
config.CreateMap().ForAllMembers(TreatEmptyStringsAsNull);

The error message I received is that "using generic type IMemberConfigurationExpression requires three arguments.

My attempted fix:

```
 private void TreatEmptyStringsAsNull<TSource, TDestination, TMember>(IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember> expression)
    {

        expression.Condition(ctx => ctx.SourceType != typeof(string) || (string)ctx.SourceValue != string.Empty); 
    }
```

But then I got a new error "TSource does not contain a definition for 'SourceType' and no extension method 'SourceType' accepting a first argument of type 'TSource' could be found."

How should I update this helper method to make it work?

**#Update:**
I did the following changes which no longer cause any error:

```
    private static void TreatEmptyStringsAsNull<TSource, TDestination, TMember>(IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource,TDestination, TMember> expression)
    {
        expression.Condition(ctx => ctx.GetType() != typeof(string) || ctx.ToString() != string.Empty); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static void TreatEmptyStringsAsNull<TSource, TDestination, TMember>(IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource,TDestination, TMember> expression)
{
    expression.Condition(ctx => ctx.GetType() != typeof(string) || ctx.ToString() != string.Empty); 
}
```

This worked.